# How to convert nvarchar value '********' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

How do I convert a `nvarchar` value '********' to data type `int`?

Column `TransactionDate` there is a column, some of which have a value of '********'

```sql
select 
    PolicyNumber
    ,PlanType
    ,Premium
    ,TransactionDate
    ,PostDate 
from 
    EasyCover 
where 
    transactionDate >= 20170101
```

Comment: Do you want to convert it from nvarchar to int or nvarchar to datetime?

Comment: Is `transactionDate` of type int or datetime?

Comment: Do not store dates as strings.

Comment: data type of TransactionDate is nvarchar(50)

Comment: when I run the code it gives this error      "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '********' to data type int"

Comment: You can't convert that value to int, it's not possible.

Comment: `'********'` isn't a number, so what number are you expecting? Why is your `TransactionDate` column an `nvarchar(50)` and why are you passing it an `int`? A date should be stored as a `date`, and when you pass a value to it it should be a literal string in the format `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.sssssss)`.

Comment: You should indeed not store dates in varchar types - store them where they belong, in a `DATE` type column!

Comment: You have to use single quotes for a date literal like that, i.e. `'20170101'`.

Comment: I suggest that you read about SQL Server's datatypes,  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.  The purpose of datatypes is to limit the kinds of data that you can store in a column. Each datatype also has a related set of operators. For example you can use arithmetic operators such as plus, and minus with integer datatypes but you cannot use plus and minus with character datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Even if there were no rows in your data where `TransactionDate` had a value of `**********`, your query as written would still throw an error.

Consider this query:

```
declare @t table 
  (
    NotADate nvarchar(50)
  );
insert @t 
values (N'2018-01-01 14:30:00.000'),(N'2019-01-01 13:30:00.000');

select *
from @t
where NotADate > 20170101
```

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '2018-01-01 14:30:00.000' to data type int.

In your table, you don't have any actual date values. You have strings. Date functions won't work, or, worse, will sort of work but will produce unexpected, probably incorrect results. Also, in your `WHERE` clause, you're using an integer value, `20170101`. That's a number, not a date.

To accomplish what you want, first you have to tell SQL Server to treat the string field `TransactionDate` as though it were a date field, at least as often as possible, i.e. ignoring those asterisk values. You'll accomplish this with `TRY_PARSE` (or `TRY_CAST` or `TRY_CONVERT` if you prefer).

Then, you'll want to tell the engine to do an implicit conversion on your `WHERE` clause, which you can accomplish just by wrapping the predicate in single quotes.

Using the same set up as above, but with an asterisk entry this time, here's how your `WHERE` clause should look, and work:

```
declare @t table 
  (
    NotADate nvarchar(50)
  );
insert @t 
values (N'*****************'),(N'2019-01-01 13:30:00.000');

select *
from @t
where TRY_PARSE(NotADate AS datetime USING 'en-US') > '20170101'
```

Results:

```
+-------------------------+
|        NotADate         |
+-------------------------+
| 2019-01-01 13:30:00.000 |
+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot convert '********' to int, because it's not a number. You can use try_cast, try_convert etc. to avoid the error that you mentioned, but you will get a NULL instead of '********'.

```
TRY_CAST(TransactionDate as int)
```